# How to run a command if the process is Killed

Tags: python, ubuntu

how to keep the command to run if the process is auto-killed

example:

python3 "command"
then,
command running
if,
Killed (process killed or stop)
then,
run the early command

Comment: Really you need to explain a bit more.  We don't have a clue what you are talking about.  Maybe include some code or an example so we understand exactly what you mean by "run the early command".

Comment: the "supervisor" may help you.

Comment: If you're killed by a SIGKILL, you're dead. You *can't* do anything else. A SIGTERM, yes, it's possible to respond to by setting up a trap.

Comment: (...now, if you have the parent process's help, *then* you can watch for a death-by-SIGKILL and respond from there... but if that supervising parent gets killed, you're in the same place. This is why folks who are serious about Doing It Right have their entire process tree under supervision starting from PID 1; look at [Runit](http://smarden.org/runit/) or [s6](https://skarnet.org/software/s6/) for tools designed for this purpose). See https://skarnet.org/software/s6/overview.html for an introduction to process supervision in general (both the *what* and the *why*).

Comment: isn't it dead to alive?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to say is: 'The process running in the terminal stopped, you want to run once in the second'.
Then: 1, you can find it by the up arrow in the cursor keys of your keyboard;
You can type 'sudo gedit ~/.bash_history' or 'history | less' in the terminal to see the history commands you entered.

If you want to say is: 'Your process may be stopped for some reason, but you want it to start running again'
You can try this: 1, create a script to run your process;
2, in your code to find the reasons that may cause your program to stop, and then use the conditional statement to judge, once your code stops calling the script created above.